# The fire finally got/was got under control

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

1. The fire finally **got** under control.
2. The fire finally **was got** under control.

Comment: 'Got' is o.k in casual conversation, but not appropriate here; 'has got' is rebarbative, and should be avoided.

Comment: As it stands, this question is likely to be closed because (1) it doesn't show any research effort on your part, and (2) it asks which is correct without inquiring into the question of why one might be preferable to the other. You can strengthen your question by fleshing it out with a brief discussion of what you consider to be the pros and cons of each option and a note about what in particular leaves you undecided between them.

Answer (score 2):

Neither sentence is correct, but you can say:

The fire was finally brought under control.
The fire was finally contained.

Comment: Can you say your reasons?please

Comment: This is vocabulary, not grammar, so there is no rule. Expressions are what they are,and change over time. For example, "impact" didn't use to be a verb, and now it is.